# ASP.NET Core 7 MVC : Microsoft account authentication throws exception and Visual Studio shows 'Access violation'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-7.0

I followed the instructions to add Microsoft Account Authentication. Added all the steps mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

When I run the application, it throws this exception continuously.

> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1+<HandleAuthenticateAsync>d__13[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1+d__13[[System.__Canon,
> System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]],
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]](d__13<System.__Canon>
> ByRef)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1+d__13[[System.__Canon,
> System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]],
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]](d__13<System.__Canon>
> ByRef)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].HandleAuthenticateAsync()    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1+d__48[[System.__Canon,
> System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1+<AuthenticateAsync>d__48[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]](<AuthenticateAsync>d__48<System.__Canon> ByRef)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon,
> System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1+<AuthenticateAsync>d__48[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]](<AuthenticateAsync>d__48<System.__Canon> ByRef)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1[[System.__Canon,
> System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].AuthenticateAsync()    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService+d__14.MoveNext()
> at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService+d__14,
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core, Version=7.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]](d__14 ByRef)
> at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon,
> System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService+d__14,
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core, Version=7.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]](d__14 ByRef)

Also Visual Studio 2022 output screen shows 'Access Denied' error.

Anything I am missing here? Please advise.

Comment: There is more than one type of authentication.  Most systems are moving from Windows Authentication to OAUTH 2.0 since OAUTH 2.0 can be use in Windows, Mac, and Linux.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: I'm afraid we can't look on your PC and don't have a magic ball. So with the little information you give us, it's impossible to debug this.

Comment: It's simple. Use ASP.NET Core 7. Brand new application MVC. Follow this article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-7.0) - It will not work. Either this article is obsolete, or some settings is missing which is not mentioned in this article.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.
Add this code before `.AddGoogle` or `.AddMicrosoftAccount` method it will run.

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(o => o.LoginPath = new PathString("/login"))
```

Source : https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/samples/SocialSample/Startup.cs#L41